# query replace content within brackets

Tags: regular-expressions

I was trying to re-structure my latex document but I failed to do it in a single query regex.  My goal was to the following transformation:

```
\item[root] → \item \textbf{root}
```

I tied grouping the content withing the brackets and then using in the replacement but it did not work.

This was my attempt:

```
Alt-S-% \\[\(.*\)] RET \\textbf{\1} RET
```

I tried playing with the regexp-builder but it seems to have a slightly different syntax than then replace-regexp command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`\` escapes `[` and itself, so `\\` matches a backslash and `\[` matches an open bracket.  So `\\[\(.*\)]` matches a backslash followed by a dot, a parenthesis or a star.

Instead, you presumably wanted to use `\[\(.*\)]` which should give you the right result.  Rather than re-builder, you can also use:

```
C-s M-r \[\(.*\)] M-% \\textbf{\1} RET
```

which also gives you interactive feedback about your regexp.

Comment: Thanks for the tip of C-s and then M-% it is better for this task.